# Load specific php module for directory - Apache 2.4 CentOS 7

Tags: centos, apache-2.4

Inside /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/ I have a conf file called 10-php54-php.conf which I use to specify what PHP version I want to use.
I can freely switch between PHP 7.2 and PHP 5.4 by commenting line 2 and uncommenting line 3.

Is there a way to specify that I want to use PHP 5.4 in a specific directory and leave the rest of Apache using 7.2? I saw a few guides on our beloved Google telling me to use php-fpm but I'd like to use these .so files if possible.

/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php54-php.conf:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
     LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
     #LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp54-php5.so
</IfModule>
```

I already tried some variations inside httpd.conf but apache won't start:

```
<Directory "var/www/html/directory">
        LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp54-php5.so # tried with LoadModule and Include
</Directory>
```

Apache 2.4.6, CentOS 7.4.

**EDIT:** When putting LoadModule inside my virtualhost, it fails to restart when running *apachectl graceful*.

/etc/httpd/sites-enabled/domain.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain2.com
        ServerAlias *.domain2.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domain2.com-access.log combined
        php_admin_value default_charset UTF-8

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName service.domain1.com
        ServerAdmin admin@domain2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/service
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/service.domain1.com-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/service.domain1.com-access.log combined
       #LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp54-php5.so
</VirtualHost>
```

journalctl -xe:

```
Mai 22 11:33:08 host.host polkitd[700]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:14527:379023715 (system bus name :1.15226 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notif
Mai 22 11:33:09 host.host httpd[14533]: [Wed May 22 11:33:09.001953 2019] [so:warn] [pid 14533] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Mai 22 11:33:09 host.host kernel: httpd[14533]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f46635326b7 sp 00007fff2214f1d8 error 4 in libphp7.so[7f4663284000+45a000]
Mai 22 11:33:09 host.host systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=killed status=11
Mai 22 11:33:09 host.host systemd[1]: Reload failed for The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't load two different PHP modules at the same time. Full stop. This is why you must use php-fpm to run different PHP versions.

Comment: I installed php-fpm by running _yum install php54-php-fpm_, started it by running _service php54-php-fpm start_ and added _ProxyPassMatch ^/service(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/service/$1_ to my virtualhost. Apachectl graceful didn't return any errors but phpinfo() still shows PHP 7.2. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: @MateusScheper BOTH PHP versions must be installed using php-fpm and you have to remove mod_php.

Comment: Ah, I see. I won't be able to test it again this week, but I'll look into it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can only use [`LoadModule`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/de/mod/mod_so.html#loadmodule) in the context of a server config (`httpd.conf`) or virtual host. It does not work in a directory context.

Comment: I tried using it inside my virtualhost, but when I run apachectl graceful, it fails. I added some info to the post.

Comment: There seems to be a conflict with the php7 module. Does it work if you comment the line in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-php54-php.conf`?

Comment: It's a production server and I won't be able to change PHP version on the entire Apache, so I'll look into it when I get the chance. Thank you very much for your help.